# Counting sort used on alphanumerical data?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sorting, while-loop, counting

I have to sort an alphanumerical database using the Counting sort for my project, and the code I have keeps on giving me errors. I have a txt file with alphanumeric values stored, an e.g. is 86K4G9F8124. (There are 10000 random ones in the txt file). This is the code I have in visual studio (it is in C#) and gives me an error on the line: while (counts[i].CompareTo(f) > 0).

Here it is:

```
{
    ArrayList Data = new ArrayList();
    Stopwatch SW = new Stopwatch();
    StreamWriter SWr = new StreamWriter("Time.txt");
    int j = 100;

    while (j != 10000)
    {
        ReadData(ref Data, j);
        SW.Start();
        CountingSort(Data);
        SW.Stop();
        SWr.WriteLine("{0} {1}", j, SW.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine(j);
        SW.Reset();
        j = j + 100;
        Data.Clear();
    }
    SWr.Close();
}

static void CountingSort(ArrayList Data)
{
    // O(1)
    string max, b;
    max = (string)Data[0];

    // O(N)
    for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++)
    {
        b = (string)Data[i];
        if (b.CompareTo(max) > 0)
        {
            max = b;
        }
    }

    // Space complexity O(N+K)
    string counts = (string)Data[0];
    string output =(string)Data[Data.Count - 1];

    string c;
    // O(N)
    for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count; i++)
    {
        c = (string)Data[i];
        counts = c;
    }

    string d;
    string e;
    string f = " ";
    // O(N+K)
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.Length; i++)
    {
        while (counts[i].CompareTo(f) > 0)
        {
            d = (string)Data[i];
            output= d;
            e = (string)Data[i--];
            counts = e;
        }
    }
}

static void ReadData(ref ArrayList data, int Times)
{
    StreamReader SR = new StreamReader("Data.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < Times; i++)
    {
        data.Add(SR.ReadLine());
    }
    SR.Close();
}
```

Please could someone help me and tell me where I am going wrong and hopefully what to do. Thanks!

Comment: What is the error it gives? `counts` is a string, when you index into it, you are returned the character at that index, so must likely the error is that you're comparing incompatible types. C# is statically typed, f is a string, counts is a string, counts[i] is a char, `char == string` is not allowed in C# as it has a strict type system.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal the error says: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
I understand what you mean, but how can I do the sorting count for alphanumeric data then? Thanks

Comment: You're getting an argument exception because you're calling this method; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhh2bx3h(v=vs.110).aspx (or the other version which accepts and `object` as the argument) but passing it a string. If you used the equality operator (`==`) then you would get a compiler error but since the method has an overload accepting type `object` it attempts to call that method then throws when it realizes it cannot compare string to char. I'll post an answer with a minor change that will at least fix that problem, you may still have other issues in your logic though.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a `System.ArgumentException` because you're passing the wrong type into `CompareTo`. In the code below, `counts[i]` is indexing into the string, meaning the thing you actually call `CompareTo` on is a `char`. There are many versions of `CompareTo` (more than one for both chars and strings in fact). While this may not fully resolve the issues in your program (I haven't tested it to say one way or another) simply changing the type of `f` from `string` to `char` will resolve the problem you're facing currently.

```
char f = ' ';
// O(N+K)
for (int i = 0; i < counts.Length; i++)
{
    while (counts[i].CompareTo(f) > 0)
    {
        d = (string)Data[i];
        output= d;
        e = (string)Data[i--];
        counts = e;
    }
}
```

If you read the remarks on `CompareTo` here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he5tb5hy(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll find this behavior is documented. Your code compiles because there is an overload of `CompareTo` which accepts and `object` as it's argument, and `string` inherits from `object` so this method call is allowed, however, if the `object` passed into it is not `null` or an instance of type `char` then it throws an `ArgumentException` so basically, just go through your code and make sure that you're comparing chars to chars and strings to strings and you should be good to go, baring any errors in the actual sorting logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `counts` is a `string`, not an array or list of `string`'s.
I didn't understood much of the code but try matching the types (Maybe replacing `counts` with `Data`? Again, didn't understood much but seems appropriate)

Comment: are you saying that I must make counts an arraylist instead of a string?

Comment: Sorry but from what I know about Counting Sort (read five minutes right now on Wikipedia) it is not possible on strings at all... I don't get what this code does...